# Method must have a return type

Tags: c#, function, methods

Can someone help me? I'm trying to make this function public and C# is telling me that I need a return type. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
static public KeepGoing()
```

Comment: Give the method a return type!

Comment: `public static void KeepGoing()`

Comment: kindly google first; u'll definitely find an example

Comment: Ok. Thanks, King.Code. Using void worked. Sorry if my post made me seem lazy. I'm new to programming, and I get stuck pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always want to put the return value after the access modifier.
IF the method is static then put it after the `static` keyword.

```
// returns nothing 
public void KeepGoing() { }

// returns a string
public string KeepGoing()
{
    return "Keep going!";
}

// returns a number
public int KeepGoing()
{
    return 3;
}

// static method that returns a string
public static string KeepGoing()
{
    return "This is static!";
}
```